# Convert the following jQuery to pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would one convert the following commented lines to pure JS?

```
var countdown = Tock({
    callback: function () {   

        $('#countdown_clock').val(timer.msToTime(countdown.lap()));  // Convert to pure JS
    }
});

$('#startCountdown').on('click', function () { 

    countdown.start(countdown.timeToMS($('#countdown_clock').val())); // Convert to pure JS 
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove all traces of jQuery in your code

```
var countdown = Tock({
    callback: function () {
        //$('#countdown_clock').val(timer.msToTime(countdown.lap())); // Convert to pure JS
         document.getElementById('countdown_clock').value = timer.msToTime(countdown.lap());
    }
});
//$('#startCountdown').on('click', function () {
document.getElementById('startCountdown').onclick = function(e){

    //countdown.start(countdown.timeToMS($('#countdown_clock').val())); // Convert to pure JS
    countdown.start(countdown.timeToMS(getElementById('countdown_clock').value);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementById` instead of jQuery selector `$("#...")`

1. ```
   document.getElementById('countdown_clock').value = timer.msToTime(countdown.lap();
   ```
2. ```
   countdown.start(countdown.timeToMS(document.getElementById('countdown_clock').value));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `$('#selector')` is the same thing with JS `document.getElementById('selector')`

Try:

```
var countdown = Tock({
    callback: function () {
       document.getElementById('countdown_clock').value=timer.msToTime(countdown.lap());

    }
});

$('#startCountdown').on('click', function () {
      countdown.start(countdown.timeToMS(document.getElementById('countdown_clock').value));
});
```

Comment: it still uses the jQuery event listener

Comment: @zoranc Read the question! The OP says  following commented lines only. Not the whole code!

Comment: missed that part reversed the -1 to +1

Comment: the title was a bit misleading as it read "Convert the following jQuery to pure JS"

Answer (score 1):

Pure Js

```
var clock = document.getElementById('countdown_clock');
var countdown = Tock({
callback: function () {   
    // Convert to pure JS
    clock.value = timer.msToTime(countdown.lap()); 
   }
});

document.getElementById('startCountdown').addEventListener('click', function(){
countdown.start(countdown.timeToMS(clock.value));
}, false);
```